# Bandwidth speeds better over Ubuntu than Windows

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7

I have a weird issue on my Dell server.  When I check the bandwidth using the tool Iperf against my Amazon Server I get bandwidth of 11 Mbps over Windows 7 Professional. On the same machine when I use Ubuntu against my Amazon server I receive speeds of 90 Mbps - a huge leap of bandwidth.

Can anyone tell me why I am experiencing such drastic differences in bandwidth speeds?

Comment: Bandwidth != Speed.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite possibly running into problems with Windows's TCP Chimney Offload, Receive Side Scaling, and/or Network Direct Memory Access. Inspect [Microsoft KB951037](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951037) for more information about each of those features and how to disable them.

I've also come across issues with [Windows Network Task Offload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463469). I had to disable it using an obscure registry key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`

Add a new DWORD and give it the name DisableTaskOffload. Set the value on the new DWORD to 1. For more info, see a blog post I wrote titled "[Fixing Exceptionally Slow Remote Desktop Performance to Windows Server 2008.](http://thenubbyadmin.com/2012/02/14/fixing-exceptionally-slow-remote-desktop-performance-to-windows-server-2008/)"

Comment: Thanks Wesley. I have tried that but it hasnt helped me. I am still unable to increase the bandwidth speed over Windows.

Comment: Did you make sure to reboot after each change to the stack?

Comment: Yes Sir.Did that as well but no luck. The bandwidth still shows as 11 odd mbps where i have a 100mbps connection

Comment: Are both ends a Windows machine? I'm not sure if the endpoint that the Windows 7 machine is trying to communicate with is also a Windows machine. These steps should be taken on both ends of the communication as part of troubleshooting. I had to disable Network Task Offloading on server and client to get my connection speeds to even out.

Comment: The amazon end is a Linux machine while the server on my end is a Windows 7 machine. When I use Ubuntu instead of Windows everything is hunky-dory.

Comment: Could this be a MBs vs mbs issue?

Comment: No Jim, its not the issue of MB's over mbs.

Comment: TCP Window scaling?

Comment: I have tried the windows scaling as well and it doesnt change things. Infact, I am ready to take on a consultant who can help us solve this issue.